# How to make a link not to "Open in new window"

Tags: javascript, jquery

When we click with right mouse button on a any site link, there's a dropdown menu. One of the options here is "Open in new window". For some reasons, I need to disable this possibility for all site links. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

#### The reason for doing this

The site menu has 2 types of menu items: ordinary links to pages and fake links, that cause popup window with certain information. I have a jquery function, that shows this popup and returns false for the link. And when a user "Open in new window" some of fake links, page reloads, but popup does not appear. And the user is looking at the empty page. That's not good I think :)

Comment: You can, but I don't think anyone would recommend you doing it unless it's an Intranet website and there is a concrete reason to do it.

Comment: @NinjaBomb This option is a browser specific feature that cant be controlled via JavaScript. Also, if there was such an option it would most likely have an inconsistent interface across browsers.

Comment: The problem is that you have fake links, [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It's possible to disable context menu on any element we want:

```
$('selector').contextmenu( function() {
    return false;
});
```

To disable context menu on the page completely, we can use the following:

```
$('*').contextmenu( function() {
    return false;
});
```

**OLD ANSWER**

OK, guys, if we can't change browsers specific features, then we have to think of some other way. As for me, the most suitable idea has been suggested by Quentin. So I wrote a little jquery script to replace all links, that I need to be fake, with span elements.

```
// transform links with .fake class only
$('.nav >li > a.fake').each(function () {

    // save all necessary link information
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var text = $(this).html();

    // add fake span
    $(this).after('<span>'+text+'</span>');

    // save new span into a variable and after this we can remove the link
    var mySpan = $(this).siblings('span');
    $(this).remove();

    // emulate link default behaviour
    mySpan.click(function () {
        window.location.href = href;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

No, not in all browsers, probably not in *any* browser. You can't change it's GUI without the specific browser giving you access to it, as the browser GUI isn't a standard in any way.

And why would you like to do that anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to change the url and add the action on click so when the user try to open it in new windows nothing happens

Comment: If the user doesn't want people going to the pages outright, they shouldn't let the links be visible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cant disable this option since its provided by the web browser itself and each one implements the feature differently. You can however check the referrer value in the HTTP headers and ensure that its a correct value. When a user opens a new window the referrer should be set to null allowing you to intervene.

I would also hope that you consider not implementing this because some browsers have inconsistent behavior or an appliance on the network might remove the header information which would leave people unable to use your site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using javascript, you might as well make clicking links execute a javascript method. That way opening it up in a new page does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the HREF attribute from the  tag, but apply CSS styling to make it look like a link in all browsers. Then use a Javascript onclick function to do what it is you want to do. Easy. Case in point: look at the "add comment" link / button on this very page. If you right-click on it, you notice that there is no "Open in new Window" option :)

Comment: You'll also notice that you can't focus it, which makes it rather difficult to use if you aren't using a mouse (or other pointing device). This will introduce nasty accessibility problems.

Comment: Do not remove the href, it breaks compliance-- use href="#". Then event.preventDefault() and return false in your javascript method to prevent any default link-clicking actions.

Comment: @Quentin, this is specifically an issue for situations where a CLICK is being attempted.

Comment: @Sold Out Activist - Compliance with what? Second - I thought of suggesting event.preventDefault() but I don't get the impression that this individual would know how to use it.

Comment: @Josh — stopping people from doing something with a click doesn't mean that you want to stop them from interacting with something without a mouse (and doing so may be illegal (anti-discrimination law) depending on the jurisdictions in which you operate).

Comment: (X)HTML compiler compliance. Sure no browser validators complain, but that's not the point. Some browsers won't even trigger click events without the href in place. @Quentin: No country is going to make it illegal for someone to disable click functionality on their own site. That would mean a large portion of javascript-infused sites are illegal in those retarded countries.

Comment: @Sold Out Activist — There are lots of countries (including the UK and the USA) with laws that cover accessibility of websites. There are plenty of badly written sites that don't come up to scratch, they have just been "lucky" enough to not have people care enough to sue. Other entities, such as [Target](http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2008/08/target-to-pay-6-million-to-settle-site-accessibility-suit.ars) and [The Sydney Organising Committee for the Olympic Games](http://www.tomw.net.au/2001/bat2001f.html) haven't been so lucky.

Comment: That's like a deaf person suing a band for not providing a translator at every concert. That olympic lawsuit is horseshit. Under the precedent set by that case, Youtube could be sued for not making their site usable by blind people.

Comment: @Sold Out Activist — No, it isn't, no, it isn't and no, it can't.

Answer (score 1):

that ain't good for website reference, but if you REALLY need to block access from new windows...

How about generating your page content with Ajax?

something like that:

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="page('Main')"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="page('Sub')"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="page('Sub')"></a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function xmlhttp() {
  var x;
  try {
    x = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      x = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        x = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } catch (e) {
        x = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return x;
}

function page(idMenu) {
  var http = xmlhttp();
  if (!http) {
    alert('XmlHttpRequest non supporté');
  } else {
    var url = 'pageOutput.php?pageNo=' + idMenu;
    http.open('GET', url, true);
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('pageContent').innerHTML = http.responseText;
      }
    }
    http.send();
  }
}
```

now all you have left to do is create a PHP where you check whatever menu ID is called and echo page content according to $_GET['pageNo']. if you already got your pages on many PHP/HTML you may also just do include and echo them...

```
if(isset($_GET['pageNo'])){
    //echo page code here according to $_GET['pageNo'] value
}else{
    //echo main page
}
```

EDIT: You may also add URL param to refer the current page so the user can reload your page from a new window without having no params loaded...

Answer (score 0):

disable right click should do it...

http://www.billybear4kids.com/clipart/riteclic.htm

Comment: it won't stop pressing the  ctrl + clicking the link from opening in new window :)

Comment: Or copying the URL and pasting it themselves.

Comment: @Tarek Ctrl + left mouse button = open in new window, do I understand you correctly? What browsers do behave this way? I saw only in IE.